# How can I make a nil compatible completion handler?

Tags: swift, closures

I created a function with a completion handler. Sometimes I need to use the completion block,  sometimes not.

Here is the function:

```
func numberCheck(number: String , completion : @escaping (Bool)->()){
     //some task do here 
    completion(true)
}
```

use:

```
numberCheck(number: "77" , completion: {_ in
    //some task do here 
})
```

But I want to leave it completion block nil:

```
numberCheck(number: "77" ,  completion: nil)
```

but it is gives me an error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '(Bool) -> ()'

Comment: a closure is type like any other, just make it into an optional appending `?` to make the variable be able to hold `nil`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the closure optional

```
func numberCheck(number: String , completion : @escaping ((Bool)->())?){
```

or for better readability

```
typealias CheckResult = (Bool)->()

func numberCheck(number: String , completion : @escaping CheckResult? ){
```

But then you have to write in the body of the function

```
completion?(true)
```

Comment: @cristainlika3 [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)

Comment: is it  possible to give default value .. i want default value false . for example : `typealias CheckResult = (Bool : true)->()`

Comment: No, it's not. A type (alias) is not an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your closure parameter optional like:

```
func numberCheck(number: String, completion: @escaping ((Bool)->())?)
```

Also, you can set a default value like:

```
func numberCheck(number: String, completion: @escaping ((Bool)->())? = nil)
```

This way you can call without informing nil to the `completion` parameter, simply:

```
numberCheck(number: "123")
```